# Trying to import a schema into OpenLDAP olcAttributeTypes: AttributeType inappropriate USAGE:

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to update my schema on OpenLDAP.

I want to add the following item:

objectGUID

To add it, I've tried exporting the raw definition from a functioning LDAP to install on my OpenLDAP, I have done this using apache directory studio. ( see screen shot below).

This has given my the following raw data:

`( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2 NAME 'objectGUID' SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40' SINGLE-VALUE NO-USER-MODIFICATION )`

I now want to import it, to do this I'm using an ldif file as follows

```
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributetypes
olcAttributetypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2 NAME 'objectGUID' 
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40' SINGLE-VALUE NO-USER-MODIFICATION )
```

however when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
        additional info: olcAttributeTypes: AttributeType inappropriate USAGE: "objectGUID"
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

FYI this is a functioning one I have successfully installed:

```
# Add the groupType Attribute
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributetypes
olcAttributetypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.750 NAME 'groupType'
   SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27' SINGLE-VALUE
 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NO-USER-MODIFICATION` flag is only allowed for attributes that are defined *and managed* by the LDAP server itself (i.e. where the values are automatically provided by the server's code or by a plugin). It does not make sense for custom attributes – if not the user, *then who* would create and modify them?

---

Note that OpenLDAP already has the standard `entryUUID` operational attribute. It might make more sense to change the attribute name in your software from the AD-specific name to the OpenLDAP one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to mimick the fields as closely as possible. Is that field what would cause the error I'm having ?